# List.fold_left implementation vs List.fold_right implementation

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml, and I have seen from other posts that `fold_left` in `List` is tail recursive and works better on larger lists, whereas `fold_right` is not tail recursive. 
My question is why `fold_left` only works better on larger lists, how is it implemented that makes it not work better on smaller lists.

Comment: FYI, you can examine the implementations yourself here: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml#L118-L126

Answer (score 2):

The `fold_left` function is indeed tail-recursive, however, it works fine on both small and large lists. There is no gain in using `fold_right` instead of `fold_left` on small lists. The `fold_left` function is *always* faster than `fold_right`, and the rumors that you heard are not about `fold_left` vs `fold_right`, but rather about a tail-recursive version of `fold_right` vs a non-tail-recursive version of `fold_right`. But let me first of all highlight the difference between [right and left folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

The left fold takes a list of elements

```
a b c d ... z
```

and a function `f`, and produces a value

```
(f (f (f (f a b) c) d) ... z)
```

It is easier to understand, if we imagine that `f` is some operator, e.g., an addition, and use the infix notation `a + b`, instead of the prefix notation `(add a b)`, so the left fold will reduce a sequence to a sum as follows

```
((((a + b) + c) + d) + ... + z)
```

So, we can see that the left fold associates parenthesis to the left. This is its only difference from the right fold, which actually associates parenthesis to the right, so if we will take the same sequence and apply the same function to it using the right fold, we will have the following computation

```
(a + (b + ... (x + (y + z))))
```

In the case of the addition operation, the result will be the same for both left and right folds. However, the right fold implementation will be less efficient. The reason for that is that for the left fold, we can compute the result as soon as we get two elements, e.g., `a+b`, where for the right fold, we need to compute the result of the addition of `n-1` elements, and then add the first element, e.g., `a + (b + ... + (y + z))`. Therefore, the right fold has to store the intermediate results somewhere. The easy way is to use stack, e.g., `a::rest -> a + (fold_right (+) rest 0))`, where the `a` value is put onto the stack, then the `(fold_right (+) rest 0))` computation is run, and when it is ready, we can finally add `a` and the sum of all other elements. Eventually, it will push all values `a`, `b`, ... `x`, until we finally get to `y` and `z` which we can sum, and then unfold the stack of calls.

The problem with the stack is that it is usually bounded, unlike the heap memory, which may grow without any bounds. This is not actually specific to mathematics or computer language design, this is how modern operating systems run programs, they give them a fixed sized stack space and unbound heap size. And once a program runs out of the stack size the operating system terminates it, without any possibility to recover. This is very bad, and should be avoided if possible.

Therefore, people proposed a safer implementation of `fold_right`, as a left fold of a reversed list. Obviously, this tradeoff results in a slower implementation, as we have to essentially create a reversed copy of the input list, and only after that traverse it with the `fold_left` function. As a result, we will traverse the list twice and produce garbage, which will further reduce the performance of our code. Therefore, we have a tradeoff between fast but unsafe implementation as provided by the standard library, versus a sure and safe, but slow implementation provided by some other libraries.

To summarize, `fold_left` is always faster than `fold_right`, and is always tail-recursive. The standard OCaml implementation of `fold_right` is not tail-recursive, which is faster than a tail recursive implementation of `fold_right` functions provided by some other libraries. However, this comes with a price, you shall not apply `fold_right` to large lists. In general, it means that in OCaml you have to prefer  `fold_left` as your primary tool for processing lists.

Comment: Reversing a list takes O(n) times where n is the size of the list. Thus the non-tail recursive fold_right function is as efficient as the tail-recursive one ? Moreover I feel like the number of operations of the non-tail recursive fold_right is twice the number of operations by fold_left since when evaluating an operation of the form : f ( a f ( ... (f ( x y) ...)  b) we basically need to get the expression until we get at f x y and then go backward (so that’s why we can’t make it tail recursive), so since there are n calls on the stack we are doing twice as many operations as fold_left

Comment: Yet in O complexity it’s the same, don’t hesitate to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Of course, all folds are O(n), I think it goes without saying. The main problem with a non-tail recursive implementation of fold_right is not really its inefficiency, but rather that it stack size grows linearly to the input size, and given that stack is a scarce operating system resource this will essentially lead to an abnormal termination of a program.

Answer (score 1):

Being tail-recursive allows to avoid a lot of memory allocation. That optimization will be directly proportional to the length of the list.

On a small list, there will be a gain, but it's not likely to be noticeable until you start using big lists.

As a rule of thumb, you should use `fold_left` unless you are working on a small list and the `fold_right` version corresponds more to what you're trying to write.

Comment: will all respect, fold_left is inherently tail-recursive and doesn't require any optimizations, like accumulator or CPS. Therefore it is always fast and doesn't depend on the length of the list. Unlike `fold_right` which indeed has some implementation trade-offs.